# What motors or other actuators are commonly used for force feedback?

Tags: feedback

I'm building a musical instrument with a hinge and I'd like it to resist opening and closing by the user, sort of like a force-feedback steering wheel. Ideally the amount of feedback would be electronically controlled. What sort of motors get used to apply torque that won't burn out if they don't turn? Are there alternatives to motors?

Comment: a latch with a spring may work.

Comment: Or a gas strut like used on automobile hatches

Comment: I've also looked at using a syringe to resist movement in place of a bellows, though that's not electronically controlled.

Answer (score 2):

Motors will not get burned if their current is limited. You can use one as a generator. Dissipate the generated power or store it for later usage (=let the musician do something useful also when his playing isn't especially enjoyable). Have a gearbox which forces the motor to rotate fast enough. A controlled circuit which dissipates the energy is trivial, charging batteries needs more.

Answer (score 1):

The types of motors commonly used for force feedback are non-magnetic ones (ones which don't contain permanent magnets), because permanent magnet motors exhibit cogging.

So that means induction motors for AC drive and variable reluctance for DC drive (if the drive is smart enough to hide the cogging).  If the power fed into the motor is restricted to what the motor can dissipate while still it will not overheat.